# Hamburger Menu Link from Meta to Main sites has excess padding

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, per-site-meta

When accessing a community Meta site, the parent site link under the Current Community heading has excess padding, breaking alignment with the help/chat/log out links, and with the pipe that leads to the meta link. This appears to apply to all meta sites (not including MSE).

Community site (e.g., [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)):

[image]

Meta site (e.g., [Code Review Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/)):

[image]